# Boost Process library asynch_read handler not called

Tags: c++, linux, boost, process

I am trying to use the boost process (0.5) library.
In `asych_io.cpp` example, the read handler is not getting called even once.
even after `io_service.run()` is called.
I am using Linux.

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::process;
using namespace boost::process::initializers;
using namespace boost::iostreams;

boost::process::pipe create_async_pipe()
{
    return create_pipe();
}

int main()
{

boost::process::pipe p = create_async_pipe();
file_descriptor_sink sink(p.sink, close_handle);
child c = execute(
    run_exe(search_path("nasm")),
        set_cmd_line("nasm -v"),
    bind_stdout(sink)
);

file_descriptor_source source(p.source, close_handle);

typedef boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor pipe_end;

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
pipe_end pend(io_service,p.source);

boost::array<char, 4096> buffer;
boost::asio::async_read(pend, boost::asio::buffer(buffer),
    [&](const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t bytes_transferred){
          std::cout << std::string(buffer.data(), bytes_transferred) << std::flush; 
    });

    io_service.run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After I replaced

```
boost::asio::async_read(pend...
```

with

```
pend.async_read_some(...
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Next step: reading the documentation of `read` vs. `read_some` to actually understand the difference! `read_some` has a high chance of not being what you need.